# Android java null on viewpager.draw

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I can´t understand where the bug is since it doesn´t seem to be a problem originating from my app and seems to be in the support library it self.

I just realized that this bug only occurs on old devices with android 2.1 update 1 and sometimes android 2.2 froyo. In my device android 2.3 and up no problems at all. I can´t reproduce this problem with any device i have or even with emulator configured with same specs of the phones that are giving this problem

I had looked on to this the entire day without locating the problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1366)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(SourceFile:1923)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1843)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And the code from Main Activity onCreate

- The Linear layout pager is just a set of dots to indicate in what view pager number the user is. The populate pager is to fill the lower screen with dots on number of viewpagers retrived by the ViewPager getcount())
- The PageListener is just to check when the viewpager as switched page and paint the the corresponding dot with another color

  ```
  pager = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pager);

  appViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.AppViewPager);

  adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, appsList);

  appViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

  populatePager();

  PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();

  appViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);
  ```

And MyPagerAdapter code:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements OnCancelListener {

private Context ctx = null;
public ArrayList<App> appsList;

public MyPagerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<App> appsList) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.appsList = appsList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    int listsize = appsList.size();
    int numOfAppsPerPage = Integer.valueOf(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.grid_number_of_apps_per_page));
    float num = Float.valueOf(listsize) / Float.valueOf(numOfAppsPerPage);
    float rest = num % 1;

    int numOfPagers = Math.round(num - rest);

    if (rest > 0 || numOfPagers == 0) {
        numOfPagers = numOfPagers + 1;
    }

    return numOfPagers;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, null);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    int starterPosition;

    int numOfAppsPerPage = Integer.valueOf(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.grid_number_of_apps_per_page));

    starterPosition = numOfAppsPerPage * position;
    int enderPosition = starterPosition + numOfAppsPerPage;

    // Log.e("ViewPagerPosition", "Position:" + position);

    int appsListSize = appsList.size();

    if (enderPosition > appsListSize) {
        enderPosition = appsListSize;
    }

    ArrayList<App> shorterList = new ArrayList<App>(appsList.subList(
            starterPosition, enderPosition));

    final AppLauncherAdapter grid = new AppLauncherAdapter(ctx, shorterList);

    gridview.setAdapter(grid);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(gridview, 0);

    return gridview;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Lets see the code where you're using the ViewPager

Comment: Done :) You can review the code now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solve it with this link.
I hope this helps:

https://vvirlan.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/solved-android-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-android-view-viewgroup-dispatchdrawviewgroup-java2922/